# Sitecore Create a custom control for content editor

Tags: sitecore

I need to create a custom composite control for Sitecore content editor.
(I m using Sitecore 6.5)
I do not have any experience with IFrame or Custom controls

e.g.I want to implement two drop down controls, lable etc. where content authors can store values and save.

What is the best approach? 
I could not find a good example which explains my scenario.

In IFrame, can we populate a layout or a sublayout? We can give external links, but it does not work for internal layouts. (If this is possible it solves half of the problem)

Or else, How can I create a custom control and integrate it with Sitecore?

Or are there any better options to achive this, Please help!
Thanks.

Comment: Please give a few examples of the type of data you are trying to capture.  From what you have written, it sounds like one or more  Single-Line Text fields should work.

Comment: Check out this guide on creating custom controls - http://gettingtoknowsitecore.blogspot.com/2010/03/custom-fields-part-1.html

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/API/Creating%20a%20Composite%20Custom%20Field.aspx) documentation?

Comment: Yes, I have followed that example, Tnx Bryan. It's too complicated for the scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the way to tackle this scenario,It's "IFrame".
I need to set the URL of my custom aspx page as the "source", good news is that Sitecore passes few parameters (itemid, language and version) to the IFrame (aspx page), so that I can use those parameters and handle data.